# A dense set within another dense set (nested)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose
1. The subset $A$ is dense within the space $X$.
2. The subset $B$ is also dense within $A$.

Can I say the subset $B$ is dense within the space $X$?

For example, $X$ could be $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, $A$ could be the set of integrable simple functions, $B$ could be the set of step functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U$ be any non-empty open set in $X$ .Then since $A$ is dense in $X$ $\implies U\cap A\neq \emptyset $

Again $U\cap A$ is open in $A$ by subspace topology.Also $B$ is dense in $A\implies B\cap(U\cap A)\neq \emptyset \implies (B\cap A)\cap U\neq \emptyset \implies B\cap U\neq \emptyset $

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be a closed subspace of $X$ which contains $B$, $C\cap A$ is a closed subspace of $A$ which contains $B$, since $B$ is dense in $A$, and $B\subset  C\cap A$, we deduce that $C\cap A=A$ thus $C$ contains $A$ and is closed, since $A$ is dense, $C=X$. done.